# (Silverlight)How to inherit visible elements on User Control or Custom Control

Tags: silverlight

I a little new to silverlight and trying to figure some things out.  I want to create a base "form" that has some basic input elements on the form and then inherit that form to multiple other forms that then add their own input elements.

Can this be done in silverlight?  I've tried some various things but when I start to add my own UI elements to the new inherited control the existing ui elements go away.  What am I missing?

Thanks

dbl